# Errata for Bender and Orszag: Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers?

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics

Apart from typos, are there any known errors in C. Bender and S. Orszag's "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers" ?

Comment: What is the probability that someone read exactly that book?

Comment: Bender and Orszag's text appears to be a standard textbook in courses on asymptotic/perturbation methods. I am using it for teaching a course. Hence the query.

Comment: @PackSciences: I thought this book was fairly well known in applied math circles. For what it's worth, I mentioned this book [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/reference-requests-is-there-a-text-that-is-even-more-advanced-than-books-on-ad/8415#8415).